# How to create logging handler in WildFly domain mode?

Tags: logging, configuration, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

Creating logging handler is easy in *standalone* mode through `jboss-cli`:

```
/subsystem=logging/file-handler=fh1:add(level=INFO, file={"relative-to"=>"jboss.server.log.dir", "path"=>"my-log1.log"})
```

but when I try to do the same with *domain controller* then the `add` option is missing:

```
/host=slave01/server=server-one/subsystem=logging/file-handler=fh1:add    (hit tab)
```

I've tried to add the logging module to the `slave01` `host.xml` so I could add handlers to each host individually:

```
<extensions>
    <!-- ... -->
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
</extensions>
```

but this has of course failed:

```
IllegalStateException: WFLYCTL0385: An attempt was made to register
the non-host capable subsystem 'logging' from extension module
'org.jboss.as.logging' in the host model.
```

I'm [assuming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251885/1697320) that editing the `logging.properties` file is not the right way to go. So how can I do that in domain mode?

Comment: You should update the profile associated with your server with something like  `/profile=default/subsystem=logging/file-handler=test:add(level=INFO, file={"relative-to"=>"jboss.server.log.dir", "path"=>"my-log1.log"})`

Comment: @ehsavoie Nice! This works, I don't know how I could miss that. Can you make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the profile associated with your server with something like `/profile=default/subsystem=logging/file-handler=test:add(level=INFO, file={"relative-to"=>"jboss.server.log.dir", "path"=>"my-log1.log"})`